# Installing GPG tools via terminal on mac

Tags: terminal, gnupg

I am trying to install gpg tools on a mac mini i have ssh access to so i can then install s3cmd.

I know you can use the installer dmg here http://www.gpgtools.org/installer/index.html

But as i only have ssh access i need to install this via terminal and cant findout where to do this if i click source it take me to this page https://github.com/GPGTools/GPGTools which isnt helpful to me.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

This is hardly a gpg specific question, it should be asked an OSX systems support section, however, I will answer the best I can, but specific only to the installing GPGTools for OSX (the process for installing other dmg/pkg's on OSX might differ).

```
# Move to a location we can work
cd /tmp

# Retrieve the DMG for GPGTools
wget https://github.com/downloads/GPGTools/GPGTools/GPGTools-20120318.dmg

# Mount the DMG image so we can access it's contents;
# NOTE: the last line of the output describes where the image was mounted.
hdiutil attach ./GPGTools-20120318.dmg

# Move into the the mounted image
cd /Volumes/GPGTools/

# Now begin the installer as root, with a target of "/"
sudo installer -pkg GPGTools.mpkg -target "/"

# Now we must fix the permissions of our gnupg directory, as the installer
# script seems to "fix" the permissions with the root user
sudo chown -R `whoami`: ~/.gnupg

# Now move out of the mounted volume directory so we can unmount it
cd /tmp

# Unmount the volume
hdiutil detach /Volumes/GPGTools
```

GPGTools should now be installed.